# Best practice for keeping local vs. test vs. production configuration properties in Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, configuration, apache-spark, sbt

We have some input directories which we use to load files and process in Spark SQL.

The directories are, of course, different on local machines vs. test vs. production.

What is the best way to parametrize these,
so that we can build, run tests
and deploy with sbt without having to

a) change much of the configuration settings by hand,
b) have developers use their own configuration settings,
c) have build target different deployments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose from many options:

## Pass as arguments in spark-submit

- Very simple, but won't scale, if the number of settings increases
- I'd only use it to pass a single argument which defines the environment (dev, test, prod, ...)

## Use property files

- Use an argument passed to spark-submit to speficy the file to be read from HDFS (example: hdfs://localhost:9000/conf/dev.properties)

## Store in a JSON file, and read in as DataFrame

- If you want to query the configuration using SQL

## Store in a RDBMS, and read in as DataFrame

- If you have access to a running RDBMS (or you can install one)
- Possibly there is already a RDBMS, if you have a Hive metastore backed by one)
- Offers batch updates/deletes using SQL
- Might require some effort if you want high availability

## Use a distributed configuration service

- If you have access to a running ZooKeeper et. al.
- In case of ZooKeeper:

  - You can update values
  - You can register call backs, if a values changes

## Use a key/value store

- If you have access to Infinispan, Redis, Memcached et. al.
- For example, Infinispan provides a distributed, replicated, persistent java.util.Map

---

There are certainly other options (LDAP for example), but I'd opt for properties: Immutable configuration values are normally sufficient, it possibly does not introduce new dependencies, and it's easy to manage from the command line and/or an sbt task.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you don't want to have your own config or settings package that your Spark application will simply read off then you could have the application take in the file path as a parameter when submitting the spark app.

For example:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.YourApp \
  --master yarn-cluster \  # can also be `yarn-client` for client mode
  --executor-memory 20G \
  --num-executors 50 \
  /path/to/yourApp.jar \
  /path/to/directory
```

And if you use Oozie then you can change the path parameter in the XML as needed.